# Design Approach : Procedure or Java with Huge data?

Tags: java, stored-procedures

Consider an hierarchy:

Brands --> Products --> Items --> Quantity.

Suppose there are different tables, linked as shown above, having 10,000+ rows.
I want to get all the data in the following way:

Brands --With their-- Products -- With their-- Items -- With their-- Quantity.

I thought of this approach 
a) Getting all records from a procedure in very basic maps
b) Iterating over those maps and linking them all in Java.

As it's taking lot of time, is there better approach than this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you need to do with resulting objects? Maybe it makes sense to retrieve data lazily or chunk by chunk to omit loading of the whole collection into memory?

Comment: Is the data changing frequently? If not you can possibly cache it using something like ehcache. I have seen ehcache handling 100,000+ objects easily without any performance issues.

Comment: Have you tried to profile your solution to see what, a) or b), takes "lot of time"? Then we can discuss how to speed it up.

Comment: creating a Service,Where 3rd Party request all data in a go.

Comment: It's worth to add to your service parameters that enable 3rd party to retrieve data page by page. E.g. you can add parameters `start` and `count` to your service query (limiting count to, say, 1000 records), so request like `start=1000&count=100` will return results from 1000 to 1100. With it 3rd party will be still able to retrieve all the data, but both - you and 3rd party - won't need to load the whole data into memory at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are joining tables in a relational database, so it's natural to use SQL for this. Java is the wrong tool, and you'll probably open yourself up to many bugs.

If there's too much data being returned from the query, try using `LIMIT`, or per ffriend's suggestion, add parameters to the query to select particular chunks of the entire result set.

If the client really needs the whole lot in one go, you can start streaming the response (I assume it's some kind of web service you're writing) before you've finished reading from the database by using a cursor. But that's a whole lot of effort, and if your server can't handle the data, probably the client can't either.